# Phing: append files while adding a newline between them

Tags: phing

I'm trying to concatenate several files together using Phing, while leaving a newline between the content of different files. I'm using the `append` task to concatenate them but I can't figure out how to add the new line. Is there a way to do that without resorting to a custom task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion of a colleague, I ended up using this:

```
<filterchain>
    <replaceregexp>
        <regexp pattern="([^\n])$" replace="$1${line.separator}" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </replaceregexp>
</filterchain>
```

...inside the append task.